# Need to retrieve html from axios request

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, get

I am using axios to send a request to a resource that is exposing html on the backend. When I send the GET request I receive an object as a response. When I print the response with console.log() it breaks the React application due to the response being an object and not the html I am expecting.

Currently I am trying to specify responseType: 'document' in the config. But that doesn't seem to work. I still get an object with the error being:

> "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead."

Ultimately I need to end up with a `<div></div>` that I can embed in my React page.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const examplePage = "example.com/example"

export const requestExamplePage = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(examplePage, {responseType: 'document})
    
    return data
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to posting. give me a minute to figure out how this works so I can edit this question.

Comment: Add your code in complete and also be very clear about the question. Show your research and the coe you have tried.

Comment: I hope this is clear

Comment: Show us the console log (type of object) that you currently see.

Comment: Just edited the post with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

Actually means that you're trying to render a promise. Are you sure thats the right way of destructuring the request? `data` has to be a html wrapped in double quotes (string) and you also need `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` to inject it into a div.

Try this:

```
export const requestExamplePage = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(examplePage, {responseType: 'document'})
    
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }} />
    )
}
```

Make sure that data is an an actual html string.

Comment: Thank you. The dangerouslySetInnerHTML part got it to work. Also, I needed to set the responseType to 'text'.